# How find all documents matching a value of a key in an array in a document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to find all document that matching for example "conceptID" : "0161-1#01-000001#1"

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59bc0bd77d7934a6a7243f05"),
    "definitionID" : "0161-1#DF-000001#1",
    "reference" : "FIIG=A23900 INC=62356",
    "dummy1" : "",
    "dummy2" : "",
    "dummy3" : "",
    "organisationID" : "0161-1#OG-002462#1",
    "languageID" : "0161-1#LG-000001#1",
    "statusTerm" : 0,
    "definitions" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59bc34a67d7934a6a7c131cc"),
            "definitionID" : "0161-1#DF-000001#1",
            "conceptID" : "0161-1#01-000001#1",
            "definition" : "A metallic claw shaped pivoting item, designed to accelerate the weapon's recovery from recoil by assisting in realigning the breech with the barrel."
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried this, but does not work: `find({definitions[0].conceptID: "0161-1#01-000001#1"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search at specific index then you need to provide index in array as below.

`find({"definitions.0.conceptID":"0161-1#01-000001#1"})`

Otherwise for search on single key you can directly search using

`definitions.conceptID`

Answer (score 0):

Solve it by using [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

```
.find({definitions: { $elemMatch: {conceptID: "0161-1#01-000001#1"} }})
```